# Repairing permissions or restoring /Applications in Sierra?

Tags: applications, restore, permission

I did a couple of idiot commands in sudo on /Applications and at least one non-Apple app now doesn't work.  (Several others do, but I haven't tried all five hundred.)

"Repair Permissions" no longer exists in Disk Utility, and Time Machine refuses to restore /Applications.

How does one fix such a problem?  I can copy the app that doesn't work from another Mac, but that's not a solution for everyone (nor for apps acquired or updated after that MB was retired.).

I re-installed the one app that didn't work and haven't yet found any others.  But forbidding a restore in /Applications when SIP doesn't prevent breaking things sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: What does Time Machine give as the error?

Comment: Not allowed because it is required by the operating system.  Not sure whether it would work if I disable SIP.  Maybe I should just manually copy any app that I find not working.

Comment: Hmm, I answered that, but my comment disappeared.  Not allowed because "/Applications is required by the operating system."

Comment: WTF?  Comments appear and disappear?!

Comment: What exactly was the error message

Comment: "Not allowed because it is required by the operating system" is as close as I can get from memory after all this time.